# WCF json error handler causes exception

Tags: json, wcf, ierrorhandler, wcf-behaviour

I have two behaviors configured in my endpoint:

1. One is for json serialization which is basically very similar to the exmaple [here](https://github.com/carlosfigueira/WCFSamples/blob/master/MessageFormatter/MessageFormatter/JsonNetMessageFormatter/NewtonsoftJsonBehavior.cs).
   What's important there is the following:

> ```
> public class NewtonsoftJsonBehaviorExtension : BehaviorExtensionElement
> {
>     public override Type BehaviorType
>     {
>         get { return typeof(NewtonsoftJsonBehavior); }
>     }
>
>     protected override object CreateBehavior()
>     {
>         return new NewtonsoftJsonBehavior();
>     }
> }
>
> public class NewtonsoftJsonContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
> {
>     public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
>     {
>         return WebContentFormat.Raw;
>     }
> }
> ```

2. The other is for error handling. So that when exception is thrown a json formatted message will be sent to the client. The code is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149037/how-to-make-custom-wcf-error-handler-return-json-response-with-non-ok-http-code) (The answer staring with: "Here's a complete solution based on some info from above:").

when I use only behavior 1 everything works fine. When I add the second behavior I get the following exception:

> {"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","Message":"The
>   incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected
>   message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be
>   because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding.
>   See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details."}

Here is how my web.config looks like:

```
<services>
      <service name="Algotec.Services.Archive.Data.ArchiveDataService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior">
        <endpoint name="soap" address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Algotec.Interfaces.Archive.Data.IArchiveData" bindingNamespace="http://algotec.co.il/ArchiveData"/>
        <endpoint name="restXml" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Algotec.Interfaces.Archive.Data.IArchiveData" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" bindingNamespace="http://algotec.co.il/ArchiveData"/>
        <endpoint name="restJson" address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Algotec.Interfaces.Archive.Data.IArchiveData" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" bindingConfiguration="jsonBinding" bindingNamespace="http://algotec.co.il/ArchiveData"/>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
      </service>
    </services>

...

    <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="restBehavior">
              <enhancedWebHttp defaultOutgoingRequestFormat="Xml" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"/>
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
              <enhancedWebHttp defaultOutgoingRequestFormat="Json" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" helpEnabled="true"/>
              <newtonsoftJsonBehavior/>
              <jsonErrorBehavior/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>

    ...

        <extensions>
              <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="newtonsoftJsonBehavior" type="Algotec.Services.Infra.BehaviorExtensions.NewtonsoftJsonBehaviorExtension, Algotec.Services.Infra, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                <add name="jsonErrorBehavior" type="Algotec.Services.Infra.Behaviors.JsonErrorWebHttpBehaviorElement, Algotec.Services.Infra, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
              </behaviorExtensions>
            </extensions>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you returning WebContentFormat.Raw from NewtonsoftJsonContentTypeMapper? Shouldn't you be returning WebContentFormat.Json so that the format matches correctly?

Can you clarify a bit what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what solved my problem:

In the web.config I simply switched the order between `<newtonsoftJsonBehavior/>` and `<jsonErrorBehavior/>`.
I admit that I don't understand completely all this behaviors and don't know why it helped but it did.